# can go mod edit -replace escape "@"

Tags: go, command-line-interface, escaping, documentation

I don't know how to scape the @ character on a `go mod edit` command

when executing

```
go mod edit -replace=some/package-name=./folder/@folder/package-folder
```

the resulting go.mod is broken due to the '@' in '@folder' like this

```
replace some/package-name => ./folder/ folder/package-folder // note the white space in front of folder
```

Is there a way to scape the '@' so that the `go mod edit` command does not think this is a version?

my go version

```
go version go1.20.5 darwin/arm64
```